Why doesn't nginx work without default_server?
I want to be able to use 2 different certs on my nginx reverse proxy, one for my domain and one for internal LAN use to encrypt my LAN traffic. From what I understand, having a server block with
server_name 10.0.0.103;
should result in the server block applying to traffic to 10.0.0.103. However when I go to this address without default_server in that server block, it wants to use a cert from a different server block, even though there is cert info within the 10.0.0.103 server block... In other words, without default_server being there, 10.0.0.103 wants to use the cert for domain.dev.
internal:
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name 10.0.0.103;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    location /quantum/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.102:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

external:
server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name domain.dev www.domain.dev;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.dev/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.dev/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /wee/ {
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.101:809/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}


There is always a default server. If it's not declared explicitly it's the first one.

For SSL/TLS (HTTPS) connections the server block is selected using Server Name Indication aka SNI which ONLY allows a domain name; for an IP address the browser/client cannot send SNI, so nginx can only use the default server config.
